# How to remove the highlighting bar when typing code in Netbeans 11?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-11

In Apache Netbeans 11.1, I use **Nimbus** and Netbeans light theme. This light theme has a problem that I find really annoying.

As shown in pictures below, when I type **pub** (for public) and stop half way, the row turns black, which makes the code not readable. If I finish the `public` keyword, the row will turn to a color set at `Highlight Caret Row`.

So how can I remove the black row when typing?

When Typing:
[image: WhenTyping]

Finished:
[image: Finished]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It's quite simple but I did not look up carefully. So here is the trick.

This black color bar comes from the `Fixable Error` of `Annotations`. So just changing the background of this `Fixable Error` category from dark color to any color will do the work. (Have to close and re-open the code editor to see the change) .

Here I changed to white background, and it's gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with these settings:

- Auto Popup Completion Window
- Auto Popup Documentation Window
- Display Documentation Next to Completion

[image]

Comment: I tried but it did not solved the problem. What I mean is to remove/change the black color row at line 21, so the word will be more visible to read.